# How to see running java program console logs in Linux

Tags: java, linux

I am running a java program in a server, I have `System.out.println()` statements for current status and I also have `LOGGER` statements for debugging purpose in that program, I used `java -cp "myjar.jar" pack.Test` command to run my class. It is running successfully and I am able to see console logs, unfortunately I got disconnected from server due to network issue, again I connected , when I check the process using `ps aux| grep myjar` it is still running but I am not getting console logs. I can see `LOGGER` logs using `tailf` command but I want to see current console output statements. I cant kill and run the process again because it is handling huge data I am running this program from last 12 hours and it takes 12 more hours to finish

Comment: You can't. The program output is still sent to the (now dead) connection, and are simply discarded. Next time, make sure your log file includes everything to need, since that is the "permanent" record anyway.

Comment: ... and/or run it under something that knows how to recover from loss of terminal like `screen` or `tmux`, or redirect output to a file that you can `tail -f` and if necessary prevent buffering with something like `unbuffer` or `stdbuf`.

Answer (score 0):

first:

```
java -jar admin-core-0.0.1.jar > output.log 2>&1 &
```

then:

```
tail -f output.log
```